# Focus on absolute element

Tags: javascript, css, angular, focus, css-position

I have a button witch shows only when the parent(`parent-class`) element is hover. The parent-class has `position:relative`, and the button has `absolute:position`. It's works fine.

Now i want to have a drop down list witch appears only when i click the button.

I try to set the `absolute:position` and `display:none` to dropdown-list class, and display the dropdown only when i focus the button.
But it's not working.

This is an example code:

```
<div class="parent-class">
   <button class="btn" >button</button>
   <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li > content1</li>
    <li > content1</li>
   </ul>
</div>

.parent-class{
 position: relative;
}

.parent-class:hover .btn{
 display:block;
}

.btn{
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
}

.btn:focus .dropdown-list{
 display: block;
}

.dropdown-list{
position: absolute;
display: none;
}
```

Also i used Angular 2, so if there is a way to resolve this with angular 2 it would be perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you use `.btn:focus .dropdown-list` you expect the `.dropdown-list` element to be a child element of the `.btn` element (and in your case - they are not). The `.dropdown-list` is a sibling element of the `.btn`.

You can fix this by using the `~` (sibling selector):

```css
.parent-class{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent-class:hover .btn{
  display:block;
}

.btn{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}

.btn:focus ~ .dropdown-list{
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-list{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-class">
  <button class="btn" >button</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-list">
    <li > content1</li>
    <li > content1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```